# In Python how to view a specific row based on user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to view a specific row in Python for example, I have a contact.csv file and I would like to view their name, email and phone number based on user input.

So, if a user inputs 2, for example, it would display contact 2's information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: Good that you've tried something, but go ahead and edit your question to include the code

Comment: Can't tell if that shows up okay, first time using this site. I was also thinking of having it based on my delete but the append thing is throwing me off. I'm very new to Python so I'm having a hard time grasping how I could go about doing this.

Comment: It works better in the body of the question

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was having a hard time making it line up right. I have the whole code if you would like to see as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re just doing this one time, you can keep track of the line numbers:

```
def view_contacts(): 
    contact_view = int(input("Number: ")) 
    with open (FILENAME) as file: 
        for linenum, line in enumerate(file);
            if linennum == contact_view-1;
                print (line, end= "") 
                print ()
                break
```

Notice that `-1`, because humans often count 1-based rather than 0-based like Python.

You can make this a little shorter:

```
def view_contacts(): 
    contact_view = int(input("Number: ")) 
    with open (FILENAME) as file: 
        for line in itertools.islice(contact_view-1, contact_view):
            print (line, end= "") 
            print ()
```

But if you’re doing this over and over, you probably just want to read the whole file into memory so you can index it:

```
with open(FILENAME) as file:
    contacts = list(file)

def view_contacts(contacts):
    contact_view = int(input("Number: ")) 
    print(contacts[contact_view], end="")
    print ()
```

If the file is too big to read into memory, but looping over it repeatedly is too slow, you could look into `linecache`, or building your own cache, or consider converting the file into a format that you can index directly, or maybe just using a database that does that for you.